# Cannot make menu disappear

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am learning HTML and CSS. I am also learning the flexbox model. I want to build a website and I am using mobile first approach to do it. I want to create a menu with the famous burger that is mostly used to in mobile sites. I want the class menu to disappear when I hit the burger. 
Can somebody please help me out with this.
Thank you.

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->


    .nav{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: flex-end;
    }

    .menu{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      display: none;
    }

    .burger{
      font-size: 30px;
    }

    .menu a{
      font-size: 30px;
    }

    #toggle:checked + .menu{
      display: block;
    }


<!-- language: lang-html -->
        <div class="nav">
          <div class="burger">
            <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
          </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <a href="#">Business</a>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
                <a href="#">Learn More</a>
                <a href="#"><span>Free Trial</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>



<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use following code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>    
<script>
    $(".burger").on("click", function () {
        $(".menu").hide();
     // $(".menu").toggle(); // This is more useful
    });
</script>
```